# Change MongoDB Document Max Size

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using mongodb for one of my application.

We are fetching large amount of records from the db.

We are facing following issue when we fetch large number of documents from db.

aggregation result exceeds maximum document size

Any option to set this max limit?

Comment: do you already allow disk use ? see allowDiskUse here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. But not working

Aggregation conAgg = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, aggOp).withOptions(Aggregation.newAggregationOptions().allowDiskUse(true).build());
  
  AggregationResults<ContactsDTO> contacts = mongoOperations.aggregate(conAgg,
    "contacts", ContactsDTO.class);

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that:

> If you do not specify the cursor option or store the results in a
> collection, the aggregate command returns a single BSON document that
> contains a field with the result set. As such, the command will
> produce an error if the total size of the result set exceeds the BSON
> Document Size limit.
>
> Earlier versions of the aggregate command can only return a single
> BSON document that contains the result set and will produce an error
> if the if the total size of the result set exceeds the BSON Document
> Size limit.
>
> The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes.

That actually is the problem that you have now.